# String manipulation in C results in random string content

Tags: c, string, flex-lexer

I'm working on an assignment for school where I have to use Flex. I am trying to do some simple string manipulation but I 'm running  into some weird results that I do not understand. The code below is supposed to replace the second letter of the input with a corresponding number.

My code:

```
uid           [a-z][a-z][a-z]+
%%

{uid}   {
                char ID[strlen(yytext)];
                strncat(ID, yytext, 1);
                char comp = yytext[1];
                if (comp=='a'||comp=='j'||comp=='s'){
                  strcat(ID,"1");
                }else if(comp=='b'||comp=='k'||comp=='t'){
                  strcat(ID,"2");
                }else if(comp=='c'||comp=='l'||comp=='u'){
                  strcat(ID,"3");
                }else if(comp=='d'||comp=='m'||comp=='v'){
                  strcat(ID,"4");
                }else if(comp=='e'||comp=='n'||comp=='w'){
                  strcat(ID,"5");
                }else if(comp=='f'||comp=='o'||comp=='x'){
                  strcat(ID,"6");
                }else if(comp=='g'||comp=='p'||comp=='y'){
                  strcat(ID,"7");
                }else if(comp=='h'||comp=='q'||comp=='z'){
                  strcat(ID,"8");
                }else if(comp=='i'||comp=='r'){
                  strcat(ID,"9");
                }
                strncat(ID,yytext+2,strlen(yytext)-2);
                printf("%s\n",ID);
                printf("ID strlen: %d\n",strlen(ID));
                return 1;
```

The result I'm getting after running above code is:

[image: Result]

SO I'm not really sure why I'm getting the above results, This result also isn't exactly reproducible, the random letter and characters I get are always different. I have looked up multiple guides on how to manipulate strings and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong for the life of me. The result from the first input is correct, but the second input I try to feed in results in unreadable characters.

Comment: `char ID[strlen(yytext)]; strncat(ID, yytext, 1);`. That's undefined behaviour because `strncat` requires a string as the first parameter whereas what you have is an unintialised buffer.

Comment: You probably want `char ID[strlen(yytext) + 1]; strncpy(ID, yytext, strlen(yytext) + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

The C99 variable-length array (VLA)

```
char ID[strlen(yytext)];
```

is not large enough to hold the full `yytext`. If the length of a C string `s`, namely `strlen(s)` is `n`, then you need `n+1` bytes of storage. This is because the string is terminated by a null byte.

```
strncat(ID, yytext, 1);
```

The `strncat` function requires arguments which are valid strings: null-terminated arrays of characters. It appends characters to the left argument. But the `ID` array has not been initialized.

Another problem is that the `strncat` function, like its `strncpy` cousin, does not null-terminate the destination buffer (except in the trivial case when the string is shorter than the specified `n`.)

A possibility here is to do one of these:

```
snprintf(ID, 1, "%s", yytext);
```

or

```
sprintf(ID, "%.1s", yytext);
```

or

```
char ID[strlen(yytext)] = ""; // zero-initialize it
ID[0] == yytext[0];           // ID now string of length 1.
```

I would write the whole thing along these lines:

```
char ID[strlen(yytext)+1];
int comp = yytext[1];
int code = -1;

switch (comp) {
case 'a': case 'j': case 's':
   code = 1;
   break;
// ... similarly for other cases:
}

if (code != -1)
  sprintf(ID, "%c%d%s", yytext[0], code, yytext + 2);
else
  sprintf(ID, "%c%s", yytext[0], yytext + 2);
```

The idea seems to be simply to replace the second character with a numeric code, or possibly no code at all. We know that `ID` is large enough to hold the result of `sprintf`, provided that `code` is an integer value in the range 0 to 9.

Another way is this:

```
  // No ID array required: just clobber yytext!

  switch (yytext[1]) {
  case 'a': case 'j': case 's':
     yytext[1] = '1';
     break;
  // ... similarly for other cases:
  default: // no match: delete yytext[1].
     memmove(yytext + 1, yytext + 2, strlen(yytext + 2) + 1);
     break;
  }
```